# Cannot use isEmpty method on a jsonarray, it gives exception groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method

Tags: java, json, groovy

I am using APIs to fetch details from BMC Remedy, and the response is a json which is containing an jsonarray which is empty, so just to avoid such cases I am checking whether the jsonarray is empty or not.

This is the response received when the call is done via postman and I want ot check the jsonarray **entries**
[image]

And the same call I am able to replicate in the groovy code also, only thing is when checking whether the jsonarray is empty I receive an exception.

This is the code and output snippet when printing the value of JSONarray

[image]

However as soon as I try and check if the JSONarray is Empty it gives me error.

Failing code snippet

[image]

I know, I can alternatively use the length() method and check, However I need to know why this code is failing, Please help I am quite new to groovy.

I have also imported java.util.List and tried but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MissingMethodException` is thrown because `JSONArray` [does not have a method](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONArray.html#method.summary) named `isEmpty()`.

I think you're confusing `org.json.JSONArray` and `web.json.JSONArray`. The latter *does* have a method `isEmpty()`, but you're using the former.